# Creating grouped bar plot for model comparison in R

Tags: r, plot, graph, bar-chart

I have a problem creating a grouped bar plot to visualize the performance of two model. I've stored the data coming from a k fold cross validation into a dataframe called modelcomp:

```
modelcomp
         n_comp  Accuracy      Sens      Spec
1 20 components 0.7754178 0.8006006 0.7548485
2  5 components 0.7716294 0.7783033 0.7663636
```

the result i want to achieve is as similiar as possible to the following (made with excel)

[image] .

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `barplot(as.matrix(d[-(1:2)]), beside=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this close enough?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

df <- data.frame(n_comp=c('20 components','5 components'),
                 Accuracy=c(0.7754178,0.7716294),
                 Sens=c(0.8006006,0.7783033),
                 Spec=c(0.7548485,0.7663636))
reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "n_comp") %>% 
    mutate(n_comp = relevel(factor(n_comp), "5 components")) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=n_comp, 
           label = scales::percent(value, accuracy=.1), width=.6)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity', position=position_dodge2(width=.8, padding=.2)) +
    geom_text(position = position_dodge(.6), vjust=-0.5, size=5) +
    theme_minimal_hgrid()+
    theme(legend.position = 'bottom', 
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          text = element_text(size = 18),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 18),
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, title = "Model Comparison")+
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(.6, .85)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#4472c4", "#eb7c31"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that's great!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- data.frame(n_comp=c('20 components','5 components'),
                 Accuracy=c(0.7754178,0.7716294),
                 Sens=c(0.8006006,0.7783033),
                 Spec=c(0.7548485,0.7663636),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Melt
df1 <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -n_comp)
#Plot
ggplot(df1,aes(x=name,y=value,fill=n_comp,label=paste0(100*round(value,3),'%')))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position = 'dodge')+
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(0.9),vjust=-0.25)+
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using @Duck's data frame. This will construct a base graphics bar plot:

```
out <- barplot(as.matrix(df[, -1]), ylab="Value", ylim=c(0, .9), main="Model Comparison", 
     beside=TRUE, col=c("blue", "dark orange"))
legend(2.5, -.07, df$n_comp, ncol=2, xpd=NA, fill=c("blue", "dark orange"), bty="n")
x <- as.vector(out)
y <- unlist(df[, -1])
pct <- paste(round(unlist(df[, -1])*100, 1), "%")
text(x, y, pct, pos=3, xpd=NA)
```

[image: Barplot]